# postgreSQL & PL/pgSQL: value too long for varchar(36), but I widened field to 60 yesterday

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am setting up a db into which I am importing .xlsx spreadsheets.  I have bumped up against field length issues along the way, and widened fields as necessary.  This has taken care of things so far.

Today I received the following message:

```
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(36)
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO nvschema.txtdata (tuid, customersamplenumber, samplenumber, sample_id_db, location, sampledate, sampletime, qaqc_type, datasource, laboratory)
                       VALUES (theuid, str1, str4, str5 || '_' || str2 || str3 || '_' || str6, str5, str2, str3, str6, str7,str8)"
PL/pgSQL function nvschema.pivot_raw2txt() line 223 at SQL statement
PL/pgSQL function nvschema.rebuild_analyses() line 10 at assignment
SQL state: 22001
```

Two things are confusing to me here:

1. The reference to line 223 is at odds with the SQL statement cited in the CONTEXT.  Line 223 of pivot_raw2txt() has no SQL at all -- it's an assignment of a value to an integer variable.  222 happens to have a different INSERT statement referring to a different table.  The SQL statement cited in the CONTEXT is eleven lines later, at 234.  Any idea why there would be this discrepancy in line number?
2. The field in question, I'm pretty sure, is 'sample_id_db.'  It was width 36 yesterday, but I widened it to 60 to accomodate longer strings.  Since yesterday I've restarted both pgAdmin and the postgreSQL service, but something still thinks the field has width 36.  In fact, there are no varchar fields in txtdata with width 36 in any of my tables.  What could the source of the 'still-thinks-it's-36' problem?

PostgreSQL 11, and encoding is UTF-8, if that makes a difference.

Update: This database needs to be read via linked tables in other software.  Building the linked tables is cumbersome and needs to be done every time field width changes.  It's convenient to establish field widths that are wider than the data I expect to accomodate, and leave it that way.

Update2:  Thinking there might be something wrong with the table, I drop-cascaded it and rebuilt, again with field width 60.  Identical result upon executing the insert.

Comment: "*What could the source of the 'still-thinks-it's-36' problem?*" - did you `commit` your `ALTER TABLE` properly? How exactly did you change the length? And why don't you simply remove the length limit completely?

Comment: To your first question: The lines are counted from the beginning of the function body - if you are using dollar quoting, where the beginning `$` is.

Comment: From pgAdmin, I executed:

ALTER TABLE nvschema.txtdata ALTER COLUMN sample_id_db TYPE character varying(36);

Is something required to commit the change, beyond executing the SQL?  When I look at the table SQL in pgAdmin, the new length is shown rather than a length of 36.

Regarding field width limits, the data needs to be accessible to other software via linked tables, and they don't always play well with changing field widths.  Rather than need to rebuild the linked tables, it is convenient to establish a field width limit that will always exceed the need.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz, for clearing up my question about the line number.

Comment: Are you sure your code that inserts the data connects to the correct database and user?

Answer (score 1):

Why does your  'sample_id_db' have a fixed width, there is no purpose. Just let Postgresql work it out on the fly -

create table xxx  (sample_id_db VARCHAR, etc)

Comment: There is a purpose, not having to do directly with operations inside the db.  Update above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shoulda been obvious, but ...

I issued the ALTER TABLE sql from pgAdmin, and it really does change the field width to 60.  However ...

In the PL/pgSQL function, I DROP nvschema.txtdata and use CREATE TABLE to rebuild it.  I DROP/CREATE rather than just deleting records because the table may have different fields from one call of the function to the next.  Anyhow, in that rebuild, the field width is specified as 36.

I suspect, as suggested above, that the change, in the PL/pgSQL function, to width 36 is not committed, and upon the field width error with the INSERT statement, it's all rolled back to the original state.  Thus, when I look at the table structure, it shows a field width of 60 ... what it was before the function was called.

When I modified the field width in the CREATE TABLE statement in the PL/pgSQL, it all works.